# Why TinyMCE's getContent() returns epmty string if content is several space/&nbsp;

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Why TinyMCE's getContent() returns empty string if content is several space?

If my content contain only spaces, then getContent() method return empty string.

I want count up chars in TinyMCE's body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before TinyMCe returns the editors content this is called in Editor.js:

```
h = h.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, ''); // h is the content
```

This removes spaces at the beginning and end of your content, therefor your getContent() is empty when you only have spaces inserted.